# centroid ellipse MSER OPENCV

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, mser

I am working on an image registration method and I would like to work with region based feature detectors. As representative and because it is already implemented in opencv, i thought of MSER.

I know how to detect the MSER regions.MSER detector gives the MSER regions inside of a vector of points, a contour.I would like to retrieve the centroid of these contours. I could fit a ellipse on them, but then I don't as well how could I retrieve the centroid of these ellipses.
Does someone know if there is an already implemented function that could take care of this task? Or do i have to develop an algorithm?

The reason is that I would like to perform the point correspondence using this centroid points as interesting points.

Thanks

Iván

Comment: Already solved. Moments functions already implemented in opencv.

Answer (score 0):

The centroid of the region can be computed by calculating the mean of all the `x` values and the mean of all the `y` values. The resulting `(meanX, meanY)` point is the region's centroid.